# html5 geolocation permissions from 3rd party script

Tags: html, api, mobile, permissions, geolocation

I am creating a browser extension that injects some javascript onto certain websites.

The script's functionality requires to know if the user has geolocation enabled for the specified site or not.  Thus far, I have only seen example javascript that asks for permission from a user on a site, and then makes its decision on what to do.

To be as unintrusive as possible to the user, I would like to find out if the user has already permitted the site to use its geolocation and if it has, use that information, otherwise execute the code that doesn't require it.  Is there any function in the html5 geolocation api that allows me to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, Geolocation is **NOT** part of HTML5, it is a W3C specification.

Secondly, as far as I'm aware, there isn't a method of doing this. A quick look at the [W3C Geolocation Specification](http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html) doesn't reveal anything.

I'd suggest simply attempting to obtain their position via Geolocation anyway, if it works then you can assume permission has been granted, if not run the code that doesn't require the API.

I know you don't want to explicitly ask the user's permission, but it will only be the once so you might as well.

Answer (score 0):

As far a I know, there is no such feature and I've never heard about it, so you may have to wait for a long time...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is now a "Permissions API" that will allow you to look at what permissions have been granted to the site.

```
// Check for Geolocation API permissions              
navigator.permissions.query({name:'geolocation'})
    .then(function(permissionStatus) {  
        console.log('geolocation permission state is ', permissionStatus.state);

        permissionStatus.onchange = function() {  
            console.log('geolocation permission state has changed to ', this.state);
    };
});
```

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/04/permissions-api-for-the-web

However, at this time it is not very widely supported outside of Chrome and Firefox: http://caniuse.com/#feat=permissions-api